# How would I undo this code?

Tags: c#, function, undo

sI've been having some trouble with this function for a bit now.  I managed to reverse it out of some assembly code, and have gotten it to work perfectly.  But I can't do the opposite of what it does.  Here is what I mean:

Here is my code

```
ushort storedVal = 12525; //Value to extract actual index out of
byte[] block = BitConverter.GetBytes(storedVal);
uint aVal = block[0];
uint bVal = block[1];
uint index = Convert.ToUInt32((aVal >> 2) & 0x300) | bVal; //Extracting actual index
```

As you can see, it performs a Bitshift (to the right by 2), an AND on the result on the bitshift, and then ORs the result of that by bVal (or the second byte in the byte array of 12525).

The result that is stored in **index** is an index into a table/list.  In this case it is 48/

I'm having trouble getting that index back into a number like that.  Basically undoing what that code does.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But I'm waiting for someone to prove me wrong :)

Comment: If the range (0..1023) is smaller than the domain (0..uShort max), then you know for sure that the function is not reversible, because multiple input numbers must map to the same output number.

Comment: It would help if `storedVal` was narrowed more than being an `int`. Otherwise it's impossible as noted by others above.

Comment: @Bartos        
I didn't mean to have storeVal as an int, fixed it.  (it wasn't in my actual code)

Comment: Do you always start with the `storedVal`? Or do you sometimes start with the `index`?   If you always derive the index from the storedVal (as I imagine you do), then the reverse is simply a matter of referring to the `storedVal`.

Comment: @Dan           
I sometimes start with the index and index only, and am needing to get the storedVal from the index when I have no idea what the storedVal is yet.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information in the index to get back to the original value.  to perform a reverse of the operation here, you would need to know the `aVal` and the `bVal` used to reach the index, which aren't being stored.  without knowing these, the reverse function has infinite answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the input value is `ushort` then you can easily find the preimage of the argument with brute-force approach. However, because the function is not reversible you're likely to get more than one result:

```
public static uint getIndex(ushort value)
{
    byte[] block = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    uint aVal = block[0];
    uint bVal = block[1];
    return  Convert.ToUInt32((aVal >> 2) & 0x300) | bVal;
}

public static void Main()
{
    uint givenIndex = 192;

    for (ushort i = ushort.MinValue;;++i)
    {
        if (givenIndex == getIndex(i))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Possible input: " + i);
        }

        if (i == ushort.MaxValue)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that for some arguments you won't get any results, as the function is also not a [surjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjection).

Answer (score 0):

There's either a bug in your code or you've transcribed it incorrectly. `aVal` is a byte, so `(aVal >> 2) & 0x300` is always going to be zero.  This means that `index` has the same value as `bVal`, which is the first byte of `storedVal`.  This means that you can rewrite the whole function as `(storedVal >> 8)`.  Therefore, given the return value of this function you can easily determine one byte of the input, but the other byte could have been anything (since it doesn't affect the output).